# Cómo puedo probar con Mocha y Chai una ruta de express

Tags: express, mocha, chai

Estoy haciendo un app en express.js que me devuelve unas vistas, con la data filtrada de usuarios.

la ruta que tengo en express es esta:

```
router.get('/user/name/:name', (req, res) => {
    return serverUtil.getUserByName(req.params.name).then(success =>{
        res.render('partials/users/user', {user: success});
    }).catch(err =>{
        res.render('partials/users/user', {error: err});
    });
});
```

Como se puede ver arriba, estoy mandando un `res.render` por ende no se como testear esto en mi Mocha test.

Actualmente lo tengo así:

```
  it('Should post to user/name/:name', function(done){
    chai.request('http://localhost:5050')
      .get('/user/name/Britney')
      .end((err, res) => {
          console.log("res ", res.body); // Me llega vacío
          exp(res).to.be.a('object');
          done();
        });
  });
```

en cambio si en mi ruta la cambio por esto:

```
router.get('/user/name/:name', (req, res) => {
    return serverUtil.getUserByName(req.params.name).then(success =>{
        res.send({user: success});
    }).catch(err =>{
        res.render('partials/users/user', {error: err});
    });
});
```

Si tengo la data en el test, porque estoy devolviendo data.

Cómo puedo hacer para probar la ruta con el res.render y obviamente la data que estoy pasando en user?

**Update**:

Traté de usar cheerio, pero por alguna razón en el test me llega `res.body` vacío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente di con la solución. Para esto es necesario usar cheerio, y en mi caso estaba buscando en `res.body` pero el HTML esta en `res.text`.

Entonces el código queda de esta forma:

```
  it('Should post to user/name/:name', function(done){
    chai.request('http://localhost:5050')
      .get('/user/name/Britney')
      .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);

          exp(res).to.be.a('object');

          let $ = cheerio.load(res.text);
          let textid = $('#textid').val(); //the id of my id field

          exp(textid).to.have.equal('a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86'); //true
          done();
        });
  });
```